# Java socket program asks for public network access permisson for one time only?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall

I have created a jar of my socket program. When I run this jar on a Windows system for the first time it asks for public and home network access. If the user grants them then it works fine and accepts requests from public user's. But if the user denies it then it only works if the firewall is turned off. I want that each time the user runs my jar it should ask for file network access permissions so that in case the user denies it for the first time he can give those permissions next time.

Comment: That's OS specific and user configuration on their machine. NO?

Comment: This is a Windows Firewall setup question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. This behaviour depends only on the user's Windows' firewall configuration, there is nothing you can do about it in your program. Furthermore, Java isn't supposed to access such system specific details.

Comment: hmmm so i should provide a document along with my app that firewall should be turned off?

Comment: Yes. Firewalls blocking apps is a common issue that most user know about.

Comment: @thks..4 the info

Comment: No.  Tell them to add the exception.  Turning off the firewall is the equivalent of leaving the front door unlocked vs. giving just your app a copy of the key.

Comment: problem with me is that .jar file doesn't automatically request the access only when i run it from cmd then it asks for it

Answer (score 1):

You can have a policy file in your jar, the policy file containing the required permissions for the application. To know more about policy files, check this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html)

Comment: @Rakesh can you provide an example like for a folder permission?how can i take that?